# CSS computed showing text-align: center is applied but not the same result in html output

Tags: css, text-align

[image]

I can't digest this issue. the `text-align` css property of `p.dropify-infos-message` explicitly declared by me is overwriting the `form p`.

Also the computed css is showing strike over the `form p` css property and showing that the `text-align: center` is applied from the `p.dropify-infos-message`. then why the text rendered in the web page is still aligned left?

Note: if i uncheck the form p { text-align: left;} then it works. but that should not be the logical explanation.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: @NirajKaushal, I am running this laravel project on my local machine. is there any way you suggest the alternative? i will try my best.

Comment: Change css of dropify-message class instead of dropify-infos-message class.

Comment: I just got this before you but you too bang on target. thanks.. how did you know I am highlighting wrong block? `.dropify-message p{
        text-align: center;
    }` did the trick.

Comment: I just inspect this site(http://jeremyfagis.github.io/dropify/) and got to know that you are modifying css in another class

Comment: @NirajKaushal, wonderful effort. please post this as an answer. i will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just notice that you are changing css property of another class (`.dropify-infos-message`) which is not associated with the text you want to align center.
Change css of `.dropify-message` class instead of `.dropify-infos-message` class to align that text in center.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on div with class name .dropify-infos-inner,Make it to width 100% and see.

Comment: `.dropify-wrapper .dropify-preview .dropify-infos .dropify-infos-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-40%);
    transform: translate(0,-40%);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;` already 100%

Answer (score -1):

pls try this css :

p.dropify-infos-message {
        width: 100%;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }